# How old is Bender?

Tags: futurama, bender-rodriguez

In *[Rosewell That Ends Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roswell_That_Ends_Well)*, [Bender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bender_%28Futurama%29) is left behind in 1947 Roswell and is eventually recovered in 3002.

[image: Bender, the grey robot]

<sup>[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roswell_That_Ends_Well)</sup>

In *[Bender's Big Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama:_Bender%27s_Big_Score)*, Bender uses the paradox-correcting time travel code to repeatedly travel to the past and steal all of history's treasures. To "return" to the future, he sat inside the limestone caves underneath the Planet Express building and waited until the "present."

[image: several Benders wearing various outfits or holding distinct objects]

<sup>[Source](https://www.squidoo.com/Futurama-Benderhttps://web.archive.org/web/20111220074111/http://www.squidoo.com:80/Futurama-Bender)</sup>

**So, do we know how old Bender is?**

---

An observation:

Given that we have some information to calculate this, including his age (4, according to the season 2 episode *[Mother's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother%27s_Day_%28Futurama%29)*), it may be possible to calculate this, or at least guestimate since it's not explicitly said how many historical items Bender steals in *Bender's Big Score*.

Comment: At some point in the HHGttG books, they mention that (due to exactly these sorts of time travel shenanigans) Marvin is now ~twice as old as the duration of the universe!

Comment: That might explain why he's so depressed.

Comment: Heh, that screenshot is the first time I really noticed the painting with the head rubbed out. Is that reference to the Mr Bean movie?

Comment: @Simba I don't think so. That's the Mona Lisa and Bender stole it before da Vinci finished it. I think the humor in the theft was that Bender didn't understand why it was so valuable since he stole it before the face was painted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

19 plus unknown thousands of years due to continuous time travel; head is 1055 years older than body.

From http://theinfosphere.org :

> According to himself, Bender was originally constructed in 2998,
>   making him one year old when Fry met him in 2999, but several later
>   discoveries supports the theory that he was in fact born earlier.
>   Bender's memory as newborn is as a complete, fullgrown robot, but
>   events in "Teenage Mutant Leela's Hurdles" suggest that his current,
>   fullgrown body merely was the final stage, and it is possible that
>   Bender only remembers entering this final stage - what he considers
>   being born.
>
> In season 6 episode "Lethal Inspection", it is revealed that Hermes
>   supervised Bender's construction before getting the job in Planet
>   Express, and is seen much younger than he must have been in the late
>   2990s. We also see that the state in which he was supervised -
>   reminiscent of a human baby - much differs from the one Bender
>   remembers from 2998. In "The Prisoner of Benda", it can be shown that
>   Hermes was already in the company in 2993, and thus Bender must have
>   been born in that year at least, and possibly even earlier. The events
>   in "Roswell that Ends Well" make his head 1055 years older than the
>   rest of his body. The incident in "Teenage Mutant Leela's Hurdles"
>   does largely not count as an aging or the opposite, and fans largely
>   regard his age to remain intact. In Bender's Big Score Film, Bender
>   travels back in time several times, though the amount of times is
>   unknown, the amount of Benders that appear at the end, may suggest at
>   least a couple of thousand times. Given how many of these travels
>   seems to be between 1000 to 5000 years in the past (from about 3007),
>   an educated guess would make him at least a million years old, but
>   probably more. An alternative theory could suggest when the time
>   duplicates explode at the end of the first film, Bender is the same
>   age he was at the end of the original run plus 995 years, as the
>   Bender that went back 995 years in time to kill Fry is presumed to be
>   the original and therefore wouldn't expire like the rest of them.
>
> In the comic, "Rust in Peace", it is revealed that Bender, due to too
>   much time travelling, must be inserted into a renewed unit. Farnsworth
>   determines his age to be 27,203 before moving him to his new body. But
>   27,203 seems a lot less than what would be a quick educated guess.
>   27,203 would require Bender to have gone at least about a thousand
>   years back each time and only gone 27 times, or instead gone more
>   years back and done fewer than 27 times. But regardless of the ordeal,
>   the amount of Benders appearing at the end of Bender's Big Score seems
>   to contradict this fact. The event in the comic is thus not considered
>   canon.

Comment: You could also count the amount of time Bender sat in the Simpson’s basement starting at the end of the crossover Simpsons episode

Answer (score -7):

Infinite. Due to time travel and passing a 2nd big bang.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Bender's age is only affected by the passage of time within the time machine.