# How old is Hermes Conrad?

Tags: futurama

In [Lethal Inspection](http://theinfosphere.org/Lethal_Inspection)... Stop here if you have not seen the episode

> Hermes is shown as seemingly much younger when he inspects Bender. However by Bender's own admission he is only 4 years old about a year after first meeting Fry and the gang. So Hermes would have inspected Bender only a few short years before, or as [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9612/how-old-is-bender) suggests, perhaps more like 7-10 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Growing up" as a robot Bender went trough several phases (as you can see in "Teenage Mutant Leela Hurdles"). When Hermes inspected him he was in some kind of toddler-stage.

My guess is that when Bender says that he is 4 years old he actually means that he has been in his adult "bending unit"-stage for 4 years. Otherwise it might be hard for him to make a definition. Was he already "him, Bender" when he was just a blueprint on a CD?

This would make it perfectly reasonable that Hermes inspected him for about 20 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

People look/ age differently.  You can have someone look 20 when the person is 15 or 16.  According to the infosphere, Hermes is 53.
[source](http://theinfosphere.org/Hermes)

Comment: But it is the reverse. Hermes looks 16 when he really should be more like 30.